# python only writes last output to file

Tags: python, list, file, append, seek

I am trying to write a program that picks a random musical scale until all have been chosen, and the problem I have is that my code is only writing one line to my text file.

I know this is a similar question to [Python: Only writes last line of output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419751/python-only-writes-last-line-of-output) but I have already tried the solution to open and then close the file outside of the loop (at least to the best of my ability, please correct me if I'm wrong).

My code is this:

```
#imports the required library
import random    

#picks 1 hands separate major scale
def MajorScalesHandsSeparate():

    #initialises the chars variable
    chars = 0

    #creates the checker file if it has not previously been created
    while True:
        with open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.txt', 'a') as f:  
            break

    #counts the number of chars in the file
    with open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.txt', 'r') as f:  
        for line in f:
            chars += len(line)

    #converts file to list
    with open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.csv', 'r') as f:
        MajorScalesHandsSeparate = [line.strip() for line in f]  

    #opens file to check for the number of lines
    with open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.csv', 'r') as f:  
        Items = sum(1 for _ in f)

    #asks the user how many scales they would like
    NumScales = input("How many hands separate major scales would you like? ")  

    #resets the loop counter and picker to 0
    WhileControl = 0
    ScalePicker = 0

    '''HERE IS WHERE I BELIEVE I FOLLOWED THE LINKED QUESTION'''
    checker = open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.txt', 'w+')
    #choses a number
    while WhileControl != NumScales:
        ScalePicker = random.randint(0, Items-1)  

        #checks if scale has already been chosen
        if MajorScalesHandsSeparate[ScalePicker] not in open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.txt').read():  

            #writes scale to file  
            Scale=str(MajorScalesHandsSeparate[ScalePicker])
            checker.seek(chars)
            checker.write(Scale + '\n')

            #prints chosen scale
            print MajorScalesHandsSeparate[ScalePicker]

            #increments the loop counter by one
            WhileControl = WhileControl + 1

            #removes item from list    
            else:
                MajorScalesHandsSeparate.remove(MajorScalesHandsSeparate[ScalePicker])
                Items = Items - 1

        #checks if all scales have been used
        if len(MajorScalesHandsSeparate) == 0:  
            with open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.csv', 'r') as f:
                #converts file to list once again
                MajorScalesHandsSeparate = [line.strip() for line in f]  

    #closes the file
    checker.close()

#calls the function
MajorScalesHandsSeparate()
```

My output looks like this:

```
How many hands separate major scales would you like? 3
Db major RH only
F# major LH only
F# major RH only
>>>
```

But the text file reads:

```
F# major RH only
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Db major RH only
F# major LH only
F# major RH only
```

Comment: reading the file while writing to it is not very good. `if MajorScalesHandsSeparate[ScalePicker] not in open('MajorScalesHandsSeparate.txt').read()`

Comment: You have an indentation error on lines 55 and 56.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so should I be opening the file again to write to it?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry sorry I didn't indent it when I added the code here, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code writes and overwrites at the same place in the output file. This is due to:

```
checker.seek(chars)
checker.write(Scale + '\n')
```

`chars` is set once and is never updated